# Get registered sidebars list in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi I'm trying get sidebars list in acf-export.php my function is here

```
function acf_get_all_sidebars(){
    $sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];
    $sidebar_options = array();
    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
       $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
    }
    return $sidebar_options;
}
```

This function is working on page.php or rw-metaboxes but it's not working in acf. $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] and $wp_registered_sidebars returning empty array. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
function acf_get_all_sidebars()
{
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    $sidebars = $wp_registered_sidebars;
    $sidebar_options = array();
    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
       $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
    }
    var_dump($sidebar_options); // debug
    return $sidebar_options;
}
add_action('init', 'acf_get_all_sidebars');
```

Comment: it's returned array(0) {
}
Array
(
)
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(7) {
  ["sidebar-1"]=>
  string(15) "Default Sidebar"
  ["footer-1"]=>
  string(19) "Footer First Column"
  ["footer-2"]=>
  string(20) "Footer Second Column"
  ["footer-3"]=>
  string(19) "Footer third Column"
  ["footer-4"]=>
  string(20) "Footer Fourth Column"
  ["woocommerce_sidebar"]=>
  string(19) "WooCommerce Sidebar"
  ["woocommerce_dropdown"]=>
  string(32) "WooCommerce Dropdown Widget Area"
} this is not valid array how can I filter it?

Comment: Is this a multisite? I assume you took out the `var_dump()` as well?

Comment: Check also that the first set of empty arrays are not inactive widgets.

Comment: This is not multisite. I'm writing my own theme. I'm just paste your code in functions.php and it's returning this results. If I remove the var_dump still returning empty array.

Comment: `var_dump` shows you the values that are being returned to the script so you can do something with it. On it's own your code does nothing. You need to put it in a `Class` in order to make it functional. Your returned values are right there: https://pastebin.com/TUNWKJQY

Comment: I understand but how can I use it in class. I didn't work with var_dump before. Can you show me to way?